# Get hierarchical structure data nodejs - sequelizejs - mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, hierarchical-data

Here is table **folders**

```
id  name                    isSub   parentid    status
------------------------------------------------------
1   Main Folder1            0       NULL        1
2   Main Folder2            0       NULL        1
3   Sub Main Fol2           1       2           1
4   Sub Main Fol2           1       3           1
5   Sub Main Fol1           1       1           1
6   Sub Main Fol1           1       1           1
7   Main Folder3            0       NULL        1
8   Sub Main Fol1           1       1           1
------------------------------------------------------
```

This is the table i used for getting hierarchical structure. I'm using **nodejs - sequelizejs**.
Here is my model

```
sequelize.define('Folders', {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                len: [1, 100]
            }
        },
        isSub: {
            type: Sequelize.ENUM(),
            values: ['0', '1'],
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: '0'
        },
        parentid: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: true,
            validate: {
                isNumeric: true
            }
        },
        status: {
            type: Sequelize.ENUM(),
            values: ['0', '1', '2'],
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: '1'
        },
    },
    {
        tableName: 'folders'
    }
);

Folders.associate = function(models) {
    models.Folders.hasMany(models.Folders, {
      foreignKey: 'parentid',
      as: 'children'
    });
};
```

And my **controller** function to get the list

```
models.Folders.findAll({
        where: {
            isSub : 1,
            status : '1',
        },
        include: [{
          model: models.Folders,
          as: 'children',
          where: {
              status: '1'
          },
            required: false
        }],
        required: false
    }).then((data) => {

    data.map((foldData) => {
        return Object.assign({}, {
            fid: foldData['id'],
            fName: foldData['name'],
            fisSub: (foldData['isSub'] === '1')? 'Yes': 'No',
            subFolders:
            foldData['children'].map((sfoldData, index) => {

                return Object.assign({}, {
                    sfid: sfoldData['id'],
                    sfName: sfoldData['name'],
                    sisSubFold: (sfoldData['isSub']) === '1'? 'Yes': 'No',
                })
            }),
        });
    });
});
```

By above code I'm getting the **result in API calls** as below

```
[
    {
        "fid": "2",
        "fName": "Main Folder2",
        "fisSub": "No",
        "subCategory": [
            {
                "sfid": "3",
                "sfName": "Sub Main Fol2",
                "sisSubFold": "Yes"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "fid": "1",
        "fName": "Main Folder1",
        "fisSub": "No",
        "subCategory": [
            {
                "sfid": "5",
                "sfName": "Sub Main Fol1",
                "sisSubFold": "Yes"
            },
            {
                "sfid": "6",
                "sfName": "Sub Main Fol1",
                "sisSubFold": "Yes"
            },
            {
                "sfid": "8",
                "sfName": "Sub Main Fol1",
                "sisSubFold": "Yes"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "fid": "7",
        "fName": "Main Folder3",
        "fisSub": "No",
        "subCategory": []
    }
]
```

Here for ***"fid": "2"*** having two level hierarchical structure in table, but I'm getting **first** level only.

Please correct my code for getting hierarchical structure.

**Note:** there will many hierarchical structure, not only 2nd / 3rd /soon levels.
I searched many things, but not get any correct one. Please help me out from this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is recursive query and it is not supported yet on Sequelize, there is a proposal here https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4890 the work around is to use the `raw` function to write your own CTE request.